# App Recommendation for automatically stitching screenshots together on iOS

Tags: ios, graphics, screen-capture

As per this marvellous screenshot on another question, is there an App available (preferably an iOS app, but a Mac OS X one might do) that will take a series of screenshots that are produced by taking snaps of various sections of a scrolling App or Webpage display, and automatically create a conjoined single image file.  The example below was done in Photoshop, but the effect is what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using an app like [Photosynth](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photosynth/id430065256?mt=8), which creates stitched images from a set of images. Unlike some apps that only stitch panorama left to right, this allows for both up-down and left-right, which makes it a good choice for your purpose.

> Using the latest in computer vision techniques, you can not only make a panorama from left to right, but also up and down, enabling you to capture a full “sphere”.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [AutoStich Panorama](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autostitch-panorama/id318944927?mt=8)

...has been my choice for the iPhone. You still need to take the pictures manually fist. You can choose all the pictures which you want to stich from your camera roll.

- up to 18 megapixels are supported for stitched panoramas
- camera images in **any order** or arrangement (vertical, horizontal, mixed).
- option to **stich using high res images** for better result

[image]

Comment: Does this support simple stitching without using perspective to match the images?

Comment: @jtbandes The perspective is chosen automatically. I've not used this tool to stich screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

### **[Autostitch](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/autostitch-panorama/id318944927?mt=8)**

It's a panorama app, but you can choose images from the camera roll to include in your panorama. [The developers webpage](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/brown/autostitch/autostitch.html) says

> AutoStitch now brings the latest in image recognition technology to
>   your iPhone. Stitch images in any order or arrangement, using photos
>   taken from your iPhones camera. Just select a set of images from the
>   camera roll or photo albums, and AutoStitch does the rest. For more
>   details, see [our webpage](http://www.cloudburstresearch.com/autostitch/autostitch.html), or go directly to the app store

Answer (score 0):

I currently use [StitchIt!](http://www.stitchitapp.com/) which is available in the [iOS App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stitch-it!-edit-share-screenshots!/id554594252).

Stitched screen shot here:

[image: stitched-screenshot]